# Publishing message to topics and sub topics in WSO2 MS

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 stack and working on various WSO2 middleware products. I have a scenario like I want to publish a message to topics & sub topics. Is it possible?

I referred few articles we can subscribe the message from topics and sub topics by using * and #. But how to publish to all sub topics of the parent topics?

Let's say for example, I have a hierarchy like 
Region (parent Topics)
StoreID1 (first Child sub topic)
StoreID2 (first Child sub topic)
StoreID3 (first Child sub topic)

Is there any possibility to push message to all sub topic if I send to parent topic? Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to publish messages to a queue. If so you can refer to WSO2 ESB sample doc. It contains lot of information
also you can refer to http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/wso2-esb-example-pubsub-soa/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response.

Actually queue is not fit for my requirement. since queue supports point-point communication. we cant have multiple listener for the same queue. Topics is the correct option i guess. here my scenario,
lets say, we have one region which has three stores
reg.100
reg.101
reg.102

if we push messages to specific topic like reg.100, it will send the respective topics. Instead, is there any possibility to push a message to all the sub topics 100, 101, 102 when we push to parent topic "region"?? (reg.*)

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: I am not able find the wild card publish option in wso2 MB topic. so i just used iterator pattern to loop each topic and publish a message. I think it will cause performance issue. so i need to explore more this to find the alternative way.